# JNA Library Reload Under Win32 Hangs

Tags: java, 32bit-64bit, jna

I'm having an interesting JNA issue here.

Under JRE 1.6 and 1.7 x64, I can load and unload a library, like such:

```
this.Lib = (LibHandler)Native.loadLibrary(this.Name, LibHandler.class);
this.Lib.Initialize();
this.Lib = null;
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
this.Lib = (LibHandler)Native.loadLibrary(this.Name, LibHandler.class);
this.Lib.Initialize();
```

This will load it, run the initialization routine, set the class to null and force the GC to clean it up which will unload the library (to my misunderstanding, if I'm doing this wrong please correct me!), and reload and reinitialize it. Runs *perfect* on x64.

However on x86, this code will fail to load the second Initialize() (which in this example, really just returns on the C library), it will just hang there doing nothing, I can do everything else with these libraries except reload them.

Am I missing something or did I stumble onto something that needs to be reported to the JNA dev team?

### Edit:

I do have a way of handling this (basically restarting the java application on library swap, which isn't a big deal), but I still want to know if this is a bug or not.

Edit 2:

Wrote a test case in case I had to submit this:

```
public class EntryPoint {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println("Path: " + path);
        
        ITest it = (ITest)Native.loadLibrary(path + "\\jnaFailureC_x86.dll", ITest.class);
        System.out.println("Expecting 'Test', result: '" + it.myMethod().getString(0) + "'");
        
        WeakReference<ITest> itRef = new WeakReference<ITest>(it);
        it = null;
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
        if(itRef.get() != null){
            System.out.println("Not collected.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Collected");
        }

        it = (ITest)Native.loadLibrary(path + "\\jnaFailureC_x86.dll", ITest.class);
        System.out.println("Expecting 'Test', result: '" + it.myMethod().getString(0) + "'");
        
        
    }
}
```

---

```
Path: G:\Source\jnaFailure
Expecting 'Test', result: 'Test'
Collected
Expecting 'Test', result: 'Test'
```

Works fine, bleh, I'm assuming maybe something else was referencing it on my production code and it wasn't actually releasing it, always check weak references!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug, I haven't found a solution other than just restarting the service. It's probably best to restart on a library update anyway.

Comment: JNA is written to allow this sort of reloading, so if you have a reproducible test case, file an issue on the JNA project site at https://github.com/twall/jna/issues.  It's possible that it's a JNA bug, or it may be the system that is hanging on to the original shared library.

Comment: BTW, if your "test" is using the C library, you definitely won't be able to reload it, since it's already in use by the VM itself.

Comment: Your test should also use a WeakReference or similar to detect when the object has actually been GC'd.  The native library handle is closed in NativeLibrary.dispose() when the NativeLibrary object is finialized.

Comment: Welp, should always write a test case, seems to work fine now that I'm writing a bare test case, I bet I need to use WeakReference in my production code (I bet it's not actually disposing of the library for some reason), thanks for the tip on that class, immensely useful! I'll keep an eye on this issue when I reimplement it.