# Jna, Unload Dll from java class dynamically

Tags: java, dll, jna

I have googled bit , but dint find way to unload dll using JNA ,from java Class.
And as i am using dll to transfer data from usb device using this dll, i have to unload my dll from java class in order to re-use my usb device with same class without closing my whole program.
here is how i load my dll using JNA

```
public interface UsbSensor extends Library {

        UsbSensor INSTANCE = (UsbSensor) Native.loadLibrary(
                (Platform.isWindows() ? "D:\\UsbDevice.dll" : "D:\\UsbDevice.dll"), UsbSensor.class);

        int SearchDevices();

        Pointer Startacquisition(String type);
}
```

and by

```
 UsbSensor sdll = UsbSensor.INSTANCE;
```

Dll is loded. And here how i use my function

```
sdll.SearchDevices();
sdll.Startacquisition();
```

And now after using these function I must have to unload my dll in again load dll using above code. order reuse these function.

So how to unload dll dynamically Using JNA?

Answer (score 1):

[NativeLibrary.dispose()](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/NativeLibrary.html#dispose) should do what you are looking for. NativeLibrary is a 1:1 representation of the native library you are using (and is used internally by Native.loadLibrary() anyway). So

1. null the reference returned by [Native.loadLibrary()](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Native.html#loadLibrary%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.util.Map%29) and
2. call NativeLibrary.dispose()

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but using [Native.dispose()](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/NativeLibrary.html#dispose) did not help. The solution to my problem was this [question and answer](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/6901714/jna-library-reload-under-win32-hangs). It basically sets instance of the native library to null and calls the garbage collector.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary class loader, use native functions, null the reference to the class loader and it will be eligible for GC together with classes / dlls it loaded

Comment: I tried as you said. i made a temporary class transferred my interface of loading dll.I also null the reference of this temporary class after my work gets finis. But still it dint unloaded the dll and i am still getting same problem as it was.

Comment: You need to use a temporary `ClassLoader` to load the interface in question, not a temporary `Class`.  JNA also provides [`NativeLibrary.dispose()`](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/NativeLibrary.html#dispose()), but `NativeLibrary` has different usage than the interface mapping.