# How to dispose library loaded with JNA

Tags: jna

I'm using JNA to load a native Library using:

```
MyLibrary INSTANCE = (MyLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("mylibrary.so", MyLibrary.class);
```

Now I want to clean up and dispose the library. I've read about the `dispose` method but this is defined on the class `NativeLibrary`, how I am supposed to call this?

Anyway, is it necessary to do that? I'm using jna with Apache Spark on a large scale, so I'm loading the library thousand of times, I'm wondering of there are any resources left open if I do nit excplicitly call `dispose`?

EDIT: I've seen the question [Jna, Unload Dll from java class dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999845/jna-unload-dll-from-java-class-dynamically), but it does not provide a solution to my problem.

There is no accepted answer. People suggest to call `NativeLibrary.dispose()`, but there is no such static method in `NativeLibrary`. If I try to cast my library instance (which is of type `Library`), then I get a class-cast exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jna, Unload Dll from java class dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999845/jna-unload-dll-from-java-class-dynamically)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your post implies that you are concerned primarily with resource consumption.  This is not a concern for loading it "thousands of times" -- it is stored in a map and reused when possible, so much like a static variable, once loaded it is not reloaded.

If you do want to unload it, you essentially have three options.

Option 1:

```java
INSTANCE = null;
System.gc(); // twice; or wait for the system to do this
```

There are no guarantees when (if ever) the object will be collected, but by setting `INSTANCE` to null, you allow the system to reclaim its resources when it wants to.

In JNA 5.11.0 and earlier, the `dispose()` method is called as part of the object's `finalize()` method, so it gets disposed when the object is eventually collected.  As of JNA 5.12.x, a Cleaner is used rather than a finalizer, and may unload this faster.

If you're really done with the instance, this may be sufficient for you.  Note this **should not be relied on** in cases where **reloading the library is necessary for other behavior**, as garbage collection is not guaranteed.

Option 2:

```java
NativeLibrary lib = NativeLibrary.getInstance("mylibrary.so", <same options as initial loading>);
lib.close(); // For JNA 5.12+. In JNA 5.11 or earlier use lib.dispose();
// Time delay
INSTANCE = Native.load( ... ); // load new instance here
```

Note that loading using `getInstance()` requires the same options which would include the class loader

```java
// if loaded like this:
INSTANCE = (LibName) Native.loadLibrary(dllPath, LibName.class);
// then load like this this:
NativeLibrary lib = NativeLibrary.getInstance(dllPath, LibName.class.getClassLoader());
lib.close();
```

This will explicitly dispose of the native library (unloading it from process memory), and would be the preferred method if you need to reload the library to force programmatic behavior on reloading (as opposed to reusing the existing instance.) Note if you used options when loading the library you need to use those same options with this call as well.  Note your `INSTANCE` variable referring to the initial loaded library will be invalid after this call; either set it to null or reload the library and reassign it.

Option 3:

```
NativeLibrary.disposeAll();
```

This unloads all your libraries, essentially executing Option 2 in a loop.  Depending on how many other libraries you use (which will have to be reloaded when used again) this may work for you.

A few caveats:

- In all these options you may want [a small time delay](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/d2b2ad4e5dc37a40585a864487895795e1f17750/test/com/sun/jna/NativeLibraryTest.java#L86) of a few milliseconds after disposing, to ensure the native OS does not return the same handle.
- On Windows, even when the library has been unloaded from process memory, the JVM may retain a reference to the file itself, or its input/output streams, until GC occurs, preventing you from deleting the file.  [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74772434/cannot-delete-library-loaded-with-jna-after-disposing) for further discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add another option, which

- does not rely on the garbage collector
- uses only public API
- has the best affordance

I'd like to have a method for disposing the library straight on the library interface, so let's add one:

```java
interface MyLibrary extends Library {

  // other methods omitted

  void dispose()
}
```

When instantiating the library, I'd create an invocation handler for this new method:

```java
final Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<>();
options.put(Library.OPTION_INVOCATION_MAPPER, new InvocationMapper() {
  @Override
  public InvocationHandler getInvocationHandler(NativeLibrary lib, Method m) {
    if (m.getName().equals("dispose")) {
      return (proxy, method, args) -> {
        lib.dispose();
        return null;
      };
    }
    return null;
  }
});

return Native.load("/path/to/my/lib", MyLibrary.class, options);
```

And then the usage is as follows:

```java
public void cleanup(MyLibrary lib) {
  // other cleanup work
  lib.dispose();
}
```

And that's how clients of `MyLibrary` do not need to know any of the internals of JNA in order to properly dispose the library.