# JNA keeps state even if library is reloaded

Tags: fortran, jna

I have a Fortran code which I try to wrap in a Java/Scala code. My issue is that the state of a variable in fortran is kept, even if I dispose the library between two calls:

Fortran-Code:

```
  subroutine mySub()
  implicit none  

  DOUBLE PRECISION x
  COMMON/myCommon/ x

  print*,x
  x = 99.99

  end subroutine mySub
```

And Java/Scala Code:

```
trait FortranLibrary extends Library {
 // native symbols
 def mysub_() 
}

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

 var INSTANCE: FortranLibrary = Native.synchronizedLibrary(
  Native.load("sub.so", classOf[FortranLibrary])
 ).asInstanceOf[FortranLibrary]
 // call native subroutine
 INSTANCE.mysub_()

 println("------SECOND CALL-----")

 // clean library, reload
 INSTANCE = null
 System.gc()
 // make new instance
 INSTANCE = Native.synchronizedLibrary(
  Native.load(libpath, classOf[FortranLibrary])
 ).asInstanceOf[FortranLibrary]
 // call native subroutine
 INSTANCE.mysub_()
}
```

Prints to the console:

```
  0.000000000000000E+000
------SECOND CALL-----
   99.9899978637695
```

So the previously set x=99.99 is still present in the second call even though the library is disposed as proposed in [How to dispose library loaded with JNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41056322/how-to-dispose-library-loaded-with-jna) , how can avoid this?

EDIT: I'm using intel fortran compiler with `-init:zero`, so variables should be re-initialized with 0

Comment: Why have you put x in a common block? I would guess (I know Fortran, not java) that this causing your problems, not to mention common blocks shouldn't have been used in the last 30 years. Also using x uninitialised has caused undefined behaviour to occur, so in fact all bets are off.

Comment: @IanBush I'm working with some legacy code which makes extensive use of common-blocks, unfortunately. I know that x could be initialized to 0, but I'm still interested if I could solve this using JNA without touching the native code

Comment: I don't use Intel's compiler, but will hazard a guess.  When you use the `-init:zero`  option, you likely are also giving all variables that become initialized, the `SAVE attribute.  So, the Fortran compiler is giving you exactly what you requested even though it is not the desired result.

Comment: It would be a bit naughty if a compiler option changed the semantics of a program.  Here, I don't think it does, I think that variables in common blocks are automatically `save`d.  So  `-init:zero` has nothing to do with OP's problem.

Comment: `System.gc()` is only a suggestion to collect garbage, it's not a guarantee.  Executing it twice would improve your chances but still not guarantee it.  You should [explicitly `dispose()` your library if you don't want it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41090490/1161484).

Comment: Of note, you say "even though the library is disposed as proposed in...." my answer linked in the previous comment. However, you did not do so.  You used Option 1 which clearly says it is not guaranteed to force programmatic behavior on reloading.  Option 2 or 3 would be preferred, plus a small time delay.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, what exactly fo you think `-init:zero` is doing?  It is changing the semantics of the program!  If `-init:zero` is treated as-if an uninitialized variable were within a `DATA` statement or an initialization expression, then the variable **implicitly acquires** the `SAVE` attribute.  As this option is non-standard, one needs to read the documentation of the compiler in question.

Comment: @DanielWiddis I also tried your Option 2 (calling `dispose()`), this gives the same result. What did help is to call `Thread.sleep(10L)` after `System.gc`. Also, removing compiler flags `-init:zero` did not make any difference

Comment: Try doing it without the common block to see if that helps. If it does then the problem might be that *"Data in a common block is preserved if the common block is also declared in the main program (or in another subprogram that is in execution)."* I do not understand the JAVA/SCALA code but it is possible that the instance of `FortranLibrary` keeps the common block definition alive and this causes the data in it to be persistent.

Comment: So do I understand the 10ms time delay after the dispose worked?  If so I can post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the hood, JNA keeps a reference to a `NativeLibrary` object once you've loaded it, and does not release it unless `dispose()` is explicitly called.

The `dispose()` method is included in the object's `finalize()` which would be called upon garbage collection, however, this cannot be relied upon to always execute. In the code snippet you've posted, you null the reference and use a single `System.gc()` call, which is only a suggestion to release the object.  A better option, which you've indicated in the comments that you've tried, is to call `dispose()` or `disposeAll()` yourself.

However, as also noted in [my answer to your linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41090490/1161484), a small time delay is needed to ensure the native library doesn't return the same handle if it's immediately reloaded.  [JNA source code](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/d2b2ad4e5dc37a40585a864487895795e1f17750/test/com/sun/jna/NativeLibraryTest.java#L86) notes at least a 2ms delay works on OSX, and in your comments it seems you've been successful on your OS with a 10ms delay.